# React-native How To Put Your Icon In iOS TabBar

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, tabbarios

the problem I'm facing is I want to put my own icons in the Tab Bar iOS component.
I read the API which says I need to assign the property `icon`, with the variable of type `Image.propTypes.source`. Although I'm still getting "Unexpected token"

Snippet of Code:

```
      <TabBarIOS.Item
      icon = {'./img/ios-calls.png'};
      selected = {this.state.tab === "Calls"}
      onPress = { () => this.setState({ tab: 'Calls'})}
      title = "Calls"
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon path with the require function.

```
icon={require('./img/ios-calls.png')}
```